# batch video views to redis instead of directly to the db

Tags: redis, counter-cache

The idea is to move video views counters from inserting directly to the db to Redis using `INC`/`HINCRBY`, and, every x sec get a batch of them and insert in one go to the db. As I see it, there are 2 options:

1. set key per id and `INC`
2. use hash and `HINCRBY`

Both approaches have a disadvantage as I see it - there is no `POP`/ atomic command to get and reset the views counter. Which makes me look at transaction of sort - pipeline or LUA for the `GET` + `DEL` times the batch size..

Are those my only options? Is there a better option? What is the best practice?

BTW, maybe this is for a different topic, but I need same logic for date instead of counter (last active..), so it will be best to have one logic for both.

Comment: Why do you need to insert redis counter to the database ? Why do you need to reset ? If you don't need to save into the database you may use `expire` when you increment for the first time.

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the pressure from the DB - so instead every time that someone is viewing the page/video an insert/update happens in the db - it will happen in redis and  later on push it to the db. i do need that data. It just doesn't has to be in the db right away.

Comment: why do you need to delete?

Comment: For example, if this id have never got additional views - unless I will delete it - it will always get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we decided to implement it is to push all the updates to a list and pop them every x sec into one transaction. Improvement is 10x then the current approach which each one is a transaction by itself.

Trying to aggregate the counter and generate update from it later of is too much of a hassle.